# How to find TF-IDF vector of the documents labeled ‘ham’ and 'spam'

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a file named “spam.csv” that contains a collection of emails that have been classified as “spam” or “ham”(not spam)".
[top 5 rows of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3FMl.png)

The label (target) associated with each message is in the first column and the actual email message is located in the second column (the other columns are not used)

I want to Cluster all the training data into two categories using K-Means clustering. The feature vector to use for the clustering operation is TF-IDF. And after that I need to :
Display the top 25 tokens from both clusters by way of the following process:
• Store the maximum weight of each token in the TF-IDF vector of the documents labelled ‘ham’
• Store the maximum weight of each token in the TF-IDF vector of the documents labelled ‘spam’
• Create a list of pairings of tokens and weights (ordered by weight in decreasing order)
• Use a for loop to display the top 25 tokens for each class (it doesn’t have to be in two columns)

like: 1.0
good: 1.0
get: 1.0
possible: 1.0
part: 1.0
time: 1.0
send: 1.0
anything: 1.0
said: 1.0
thinking: 1.0
remember: 1.0
going: 1.0
many: 1.0
ok: 1.0
also: 1.0
check: 1.0
watch: 1.0
guess: 1.0
many: 1.0
call: 1.0
give: 1.0
able: 1.0
thank: 1.0
want: 1.0
sent: 1.0
ok: 1.0
talk: 1.0
yeah: 1.0
goin: 1.0
okie: 1.0
easy: 1.0
account: 1.0
hi: 1.0
dinner: 1.0
oops: 1.0
came: 1.0
guy: 1.0
bf: 1.0
pocked: 1.0
bold: 1.0
ryder: 1.0
increase: 1.0
face: 0.9664415695501261
leave: 0.9176210873329959
hi: 0.9040872022980894
sac: 0.8852067555763004
pizza: 0.869246093418147
thinkin: 0.8570998869933819
awake: 0.857007861578994
knw: 0.837215393727471

I am trying this code:

```
#Importing Libraries
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series,DataFrame 
messages = pd.read_csv(r'spam.csv',sep="," , encoding='ISO-8859-1')
#Show first 5 rows
messages.head()#Import re and NLP packages
import re
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
ps = PorterStemmer()
#Create empty list
corpus = []
#remove proper nouns and remove stop words and only keep alphabetic tokens
for i in range(0,len(messages)):
    review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]','',messages['message'][i])
    review = review.lower()
    review = review.split()
    review = [ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word in stopwords.words('english')]
    review = ''.join(review)
    corpus.append(review)
print(corpus)
# Import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
 
# Create TfidfVectorizer object
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
 
# Generate matrix of word vectors
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
 
# Print the shape of tfidf_matrix
print(tfidf_matrix)
```

and output is looking like:

```
  (0, 1109) 1.0
  (1, 3190) 1.0
  (2, 922)  1.0
  (3, 4188) 1.0
  (4, 2799) 1.0
  (5, 940)  1.0
  (6, 854)  1.0
  (7, 279)  1.0
  (8, 4671) 1.0
  (9, 1157) 1.0
  (10, 2003)    1.0
  (11, 3610)    1.0
  (12, 4282)    1.0
  (13, 2273)    1.0
  (14, 1866)    1.0
  (15, 4714)    1.0
  (16, 3063)    1.0
  (17, 825) 1.0
  (18, 887) 1.0
  (19, 834) 1.0
  (20, 2150)    1.0
  (21, 2002)    1.0
  (22, 3674)    1.0
  (23, 25)  1.0
  (24, 879) 1.0
```

I want 25 tokens for each class with 1 or 0 values as I described in the question. How can I do this? Can anyone help me?